# Lift setup in eclipse using m2eclipse and m2eclipse-scala and Scala IDE - what am I missing

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, lift

I am following the instructions very carefully from what seems to be the latest (chronologically) article on Lift Eclipse setup http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Using_Eclipse_with_Maven

The instructions mention

> "...many net.liftweb entries in the list of artifacts..."

But I'm probably missing something, as both in eclipse (after the Catalog is refreshed) and in the catalog file at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/archetype-catalog.xml there seems to be no Lift Maven Archetypes (searching for "lift" renders no results)

Was this modified? is there an example eclipse project out there with a good Lift setup? Maven or not Maven, I just want to use an IDE (any IDE for that matter) that has a working process for Lift development (e.g. not needing to build and deploy a war every change, allow on the fly updates, just like a regular WTP project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, good point, that list of archetypes is either outdated or doesn't list liftweb projects.

In any case, with m2eclipse you have access to the Nexus Indexer catalog (don't you?) which lists the liftweb archetypes.

Otherwise from the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
 -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-basic_2.9.1 \
 -DarchetypeVersion=2.4-M4 \
 -DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
 -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
 -DgroupId=com.your.group \
 -DartifactId=yourartifact \
 -Dversion=0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of updates to the above answer. Firstly scala-tools.org is no longer hosting content, it has been moved to http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools and the latest lift version (as of posting!) is 2.4-M5, so use:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-basic_2.9.1 \
   -DarchetypeVersion=2.4-M5 \
   -DarchetypeRepository=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools \
   -DremoteRepositories=http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools \
   -DgroupId=com.your.group \
   -DartifactId=yourartifact \
   -Dversion=0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got a sample project that can be imported into eclipse, along with full instructions on setting up eclipse (Indigo) with the scala IDE and supporting tools (JRebel, WTP, etc).

The result is a development environment that gives you a dynamic language experience (fast edit/save/reload), and requires no command line interaction (you use the Server view of eclipse to run your project in Tomcat6 (others may work as well)).

See: https://github.com/awkay/lift_squeryl_demo

Answer (score 1):

The liftweb artifacts are not listed probably because eclipse is using embedded maven, instead download and install maven from apache and link it with eclipse in the preferences.

[image]